# Start NERDTree when gVim starts empty

Tags: vimrc, plugin-nerdtree

I'd like to have NERDTree shown everytime I start gvim *empty*, that is without passing any argument to it, starting simply to load files rather than to create a new one, such as just by issuing `gvim` (and not `gvim myfile.txt`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The list of filename arguments can be obtained by calling argv(), so you could put something like this in your ~/.vimrc:

```
if empty(argv())
    NERDTree
endif
```

Note that putting a command in your ~/.vimrc, whose contents are executed before any plugins are normally loaded, requires that the source for that command be sourced first. Alternatively, you could put this in your ~/.vimrc:

```
if empty(argv())
    au VimEnter * NERDTree
endif
```

That will delay the execution of the NERDTree command until after all the plugins have been loaded.

Comment: Thanks. The second code worked (, and the first resulted in "not an editor command"). The command is just `NERDTree` to start it.

Comment: @Chinggis6: Thanks. I updated the answer with the correct command.